# Python: Parse numbers with non-breaking space as group separator

Tags: python

I want to parse number written according to specific locale. I need to support any locale.

It seems that `locale.atof` is the proper solution:

```py
from locale import setlocale, LC_NUMERIC, atof

setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, ('en_US', 'utf-8'))
print(atof("1,234.56"))  # output is 1234.56
```

But it does not work for example for Czech locale:

```py
from locale import setlocale, LC_NUMERIC, atof

setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, ('cs_CZ', 'utf-8'))
print(atof("1 234,56"))  # ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1 234.56'
```

The reason is that Czech locale use 'NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+202F) as group separator.
When I try to run `atof("1\u202f234,56")` then the output is `1234.56` - as expected.

But almost nobody in Czech type this kind of space in numbers. People use the simple space (0x20) because it is much easier to type it.
I can replace the regular space by non-breaking space or remove the regular space before `atof` call, but it would be specific solution for Czech locale only. And I worry that there can be similar issues in other locales too.

My question is: **Is there some less strict version of `atof` method** to get string with number in a format that people are used to using (in specified locale) and convert it to float number?

For example for `cs_CZ` locale it can take the string `"1 234,56"` and convert it to the float number `1234.56`?

I'm looking for generic solution - not only for czech specific solution.

Comment: So what if someone decides they want to type numbers with yet another separator, just because it seems better to them? How will you decide it is acceptable or not? What is the rule?

Comment: Is the data source always expected to be a valid number, or could it also be any text?  If it's always expected to be a numeric value,  you could probably just use `re.sub()` or a similar str method to strip all whitespace characters, and then use `atof()` or `float()`  The problem would be if you're parsing some larger text and there's a case where the value could actually be intended to be two separate numbers.

Comment: @trincot I do not need to cover edge cases, when someone decides to use some strange number format. In the situation I have described majority of people in the country (like 90% or so) use simple space instead of (typographically correct) non breaking space. But `atof` accepts only the typographically correct format.

Comment: I don't speak of edge cases, but of the "sloppy" cases of which you have just given one *example*. Without knowing what the other examples could be, there is little we can say than to replace that space...

Comment: @nigh_anxiety The input is always exactly one number written using digits and optionally with decimal separator and/or group separator(s). By separators I mean characters, which are most commonly used in the country determined by locale. The solution with removing white spaces by `re.sub()` would definitely work for czech locale, but I need a generic solution. I worry that I can break the parsing in some other locale, if I remove all white spaces from the number.

Comment: @trincot I do not think it is a sloppy case. Majority of people in the country use this format. If I use the "correct" group separator (non-breaking space), then `atof` works well. If I use no group separator (just long row of digits), then `atof` also works well. But If I use the mostly used group separator (the plain space), then `atof` is not able to parse the number. People are used to using the plain space as group separator, so the `atof` method is not usable in czech locale. I do not have knowledge about all other locales so I'm looking for some less strict version of `atof` method.

Comment: I understand, but what do you expect to happen? It looks like you are asking for a resource that has all such statistics ("in country A, the official delimiter is B, but people often use C instead"). Note that asking for suggestions for other libraries is off topic here.

Comment: What I expect? I see that `atof` make wonderful work as a generic solution across the world. But it is not able to parse number written by ordinary czech people. I expect, that I'm not alone who needs to solve this issue and hopefully somebody can tell me, how to make the number parsing more robust (ideally not only for czech locale). Maybe it will be some other method / library, maybe it will be still `atof` but with some option enabled or with some kind of source data pre-processing. That's what I expect asking my question here.

Comment: @enca Based on your response, using re.sub() to strip all possible white spaces seems like the way to go.  Any other locale using whitespace, whether it be the ASCII space  " ", a non-breaking space, unicode U202F, or some other whitespace is going to have the exact same problem you're having now.  In all cases, it needs to be converted into an internal numeric format that the computer can work with, and then it gets converted back to the appropriate locale format when you need to display it to an end user.